# no package * found installing mesa

Tags: package-management, mesa

I'm trying to install Mesa driver using the configuration file inside the tar.gz i downloaded on official site. When i run `./configuration` this error is displayed: 
[Configuration error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGoVT.png).

I tried to install all of them by hand, but every time i finish, other packages need to be installed. So my question is: there is no way to just install all of them while configuration is running? I tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`, but it seems not to work.

Little off topic question: i'm doing that because my Intel driver does not support OpenGL 3.3, would this resolve my problem?

I have a i3 M370 cpu.

Comment: Please kindly copy and paste those errors into your question!

Comment: Did you follow [Mesa Official Documentation Install Instructions](https://www.mesa3d.org/install.html)?

Comment: @Redbob does not answer the question "What you say is a work around to the broader question "there is no way to just install all of them while configuration is running?" - see auto-apt

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I mean whenever someone tries to install something and not follows Official Documentation, is due to go wrong. I want to know if OP followed suitable instructions to avoid finding unnecessary "workarounds".

Comment: @Redbob Oh I agree 150 % , but the OP is asking how to automate identifying and installing dependencies which may be possible with auto-apt.

Comment: `"i'm doing that because my Intel driver does not support OpenGL 3.3" `before you waste any more effort you should post: what release of Ubuntu, what version of mesa currently, what is your hardware (cpu should suffice..

Comment: @doug OP CPU is i3 M370

Comment: From info I see that hardware doesn't support OpenGl 3.3, no driver is going to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if possible, I agree with the advice of using a ppa if available, prior to installing from source, makes it easier to remove afterwards if it fails.

If you are determined to compile for source, you can try apt-apt, to install and update databases:

```
sudo apt install auto-apt
sudo auto-apt update
sudo auto-apt updatedb
sudo auto-apt update-local
```

Then to install dependencies

```
sudo auto-apt run ./configure
```

If it fails to resolve dependencies you may need to search the ubuntu packages or use google to determine what package provides the dependency.

After running configure and make, you can make a .deb using checkinstall

```
sudo checkinstall
```

This will again make it easier to remove if needed.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo for additional advice on compiling.

Comment: This is the command i was looking for, but unfortunately it doesn't work, the No package error still remains.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not always work. At this point you need to look at the exact error message and you probably need to compile a package that is at a higher version than is in the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: So, i will use apt-get install, thanks anyway.
I will keep this as best answer because this was the "right" one IMO.

Comment: For the dependencies, you have to install the -devel packages.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not answer your direct question, as a simple workaround or for others looking for a simple way to install the drivers, you can use this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates 
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If it goes wrong, remove it with

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
```

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/easy-way-install-mesa-17-0-2-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: What you say is a work around to the broader question "there is no way to just install all of them while configuration is running?" - see auto-apt

Comment: @bodhi.zazen True, I will update this to reflect your comment.

Comment: MarkKirby Thanks for the answer, little doubt: i didn't know what a PPA was, so i read something about: basically it contains all the packages i need and install it together with mesa?
I have and intel i3 M370 with Intel HD graphic integrated.
@bodhi.zazen thanks you =) I have read about it and it seems to be the command i was looking for!

Comment: @Prasqui Yes, it is a repository that contains everything the driver should need. Note that a dissadvantage of this is it may not always be the very latest version and is hosted by a third party, so relies on them to update it.

Comment: What's about my hw? Could it run OpenGL 3.3 with Mesa?

Comment: I could not get a solid answer @Prasqui the chip and the driver support 3.0 as far as I can tell, so in theory 3.3 is an update to the 3.0 branch but I can't give a definitive answer. I will look in to it more and comment here if I find anything solid.